# Spring boot endpoint can not redirect to my view

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, thymeleaf

I have an endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/reset-password")
    public String displayResetPasswordPage(
```

It was taking only `String` token object but then i tried lots of things and last version is:

```
GetMapping(value = "/reset-password")
    public String displayResetPasswordPage(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("token") String token, Model model) {


 //here token validate jobs, it is for brevity
    Token resetToken = validateToken(token);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = prepareModelAndView(currentUser, PASSWORD_RESET);

//            modelAndView.addObject("success", request.getParameter("success"));

        if (resetToken == null){
            modelAndView.addObject("error", "Could not find password reset token.");
            model.addAttribute("message","Could not find password reset token." );
        } else if (resetToken.isExpired()){
            modelAndView.addObject("error", "Token has expired, please request a new password reset.");
            model.addAttribute("message","Could not find password reset token." );
        } else {
            modelAndView.addObject("token", resetToken.getToken());//ihtiyaç var mı emin değilim
            model.addAttribute("message","Could not find password reset token." );
        }


        return "redirect:/Reset-Password.html";
    }
```

What i want is, it should go to simple html of that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout:decorator="layouts/Master" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Bilgilerim</title>
</head>
<body>

fsfasasd
asdsasda
</body>
</html>
```

its name is `Reset-Password.html`

It is inside resources-teplates-Reset-Password.html

I also added this

```
.antMatchers("/reset-password**").permitAll()
```

For example here , this code goes and shows string on page:

```
redirect:/Reset-Password.html
```

when i try to go to

```
myurl/reset-password?token=122b4e43-0b63-4a6b-8669-f4e6c623ee2d
```

But instead, when i do

```
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://twitter.com");
```

in that method, it goes.

But for

```
 httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/reset-password");
```

with void return, it redirects to `/reset-password` path and
gives error of custom `/error` page.

What can i do?

Also , when i try to do like this

```
   modelAndView = prepareModelAndView(controllerParams.currentUser, "simplepage");



    //todo send only user object
    modelAndView.addObject("mobileNumber", mobile);
    return modelAndView;
```

it goes to that view. normally it is another endpoint and view but i copied from there and this can also go that view.

For same approach, i got

```
template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

but Reset-Password and simplepage are in same folder, under `templates`

Comment: assuming your thymeleaf is properly configured and the templates in the correct folder, ie: `src/main/resources/templates/Reset-Password.html` then you can use `redirect:/Reset-Password` WITHOUT the extension